# How to mock socket library's recvfrom in python?

Tags: python, sockets, unit-testing, mocking, packet-sniffers

I have the following code in python(sniffer.py) which sniffs for packet,

```
import socket 

def get_packet():

    #create an INET, raw socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
    #current_interval and conf_interval are read here. where current_interval is a difference of time.time and the time at which program began. and conf_interval is pre-configured interval
    # receive a packet
    while current_interval < conf_interval:
        pkt = s.recvfrom(65565)
        process(pkt)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_packet()
```

And I am writing a unit test for this piece of code, how do I mock the recvfrom function to return a dummy packet?
This doesn't seem to work as I expected,

```
with patch('sniffer.socket.socket.recvfrom') as m_recvfrom:
    m_recvfrom.return_value = dummy_pkt
```

This just gives me a mock object and I am unable to access the dummy_pkt.
How do I make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `sniffer.py` exactly like you wrote? In that case it is impossible to patch it because _just import it_ enter in `while True` case and never exit from import statement. If your production code is different please post it.

Comment: Hi Michele.Check out the updated code. while exits once the current_interval reaches config interval.